# string parameter inside object in bicep

Tags: azure-bicep

can I add a string parameter inside an object in bicep?

```
param str string = 'value'

param ob array = [
{
    name: str //param str
}
{
    name: 'value'
}]
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: do you need the `ob` array to be a parameter ? you coiuld just define it as a variable th. what are you trying to do ?

Comment: but otherwise yes your bicep file is valid

Comment: a variable make sense